# Хранение информации бота (Telegram)

Tags: python, telegram-bot

У меня возник вопрос во время разработки бота Telegram: "Как лучше всего хранить информацию пользователей, все переменные и атрибуты?" Мне в голову пришло 3 решения этой проблемы:

**1 решение:**

Оставить всё как есть и перед перезапуском бота сохранять всё в JSON (или в файл через pickle) и загружать при новом включении бота. Большой минус этого способа в том, что при ручном просмотре этой информации будут проблемы, в отличии от 2 или 3 варианта, а также потеряются данные при внезапном сбое.

**2 решение:**

Подключить БД и заменить все переменные и атрибуты на запросы к БД, что бы всегда были актуальные значения в переменных. Но я не знаю насколько это хороший способ, так как не знаю как долго происходит запрос к БД.

**3 решение:**

Только при изменении переменных (или раз в час) записывать всю информацию в БД, а считывать только при включении бота. Но этот способ также под сомнением, так как если информация изменится в БД, то бот об этом не узнает.

И вот мне интересно, какой из этих способов лучше или можно по-другому сохранять данные? Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: 1) Зачем ручной просмотр? 2) Измерьте; 3) Почему в БД лезет кто-то кроме бота?

Comment: 1) Для более удобного просмотра переменных пользователя, если вдруг бот сломался у какого-то пользователя. 2) Сейчас измерю. 3) Что бы я мог изменить переменную не заходя в бота.

Comment: Проверил, запросы проходят очень быстро, но всё же, какой из способов лучше: 2 или 3? Как мне кажется, то второй вариант, а как быть с соединением? При запуске бота подключаться и никогда не отключаться (кроме как перед перезапуском)?